# InstallRequiredSystemLibraries purpose

Tags: cmake

Please explain what is the purpose of this line in CMakeLists.txt:

```
include (InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)
```

I see this line in CMake samples, but cannot find good explanation, why do I need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does include Microsoft redistributable in the installer. For Linux, I have no idea.

Comment: It does two things
1. It just automates the process of including the msvc redistributable for each version of msvc.
2. It installs all files listed in CMAKE_INSTALL_DEBUG_LIBRARIES and CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS to /bin on windows and /lib on Linux and OSX.